# showing new form on notificationclick

Tags: c#, visual-studio, notifications

```
enter code here


 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Mainmenu : Form
{
    Sendingmail sm = new Sendingmail();

    public Mainmenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
 private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Patient medicine";
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Please be noted that a patient should take his medicine now" +
                                    Environment.NewLine +
                                    "click on the icon when medicine given";

        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(20000);
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;

    }

    private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

       Sendingmail sm = new Sendingmail();
        sm.Show();

    }
```

a notification will be displayed, when i click on the notification displayed, i want a form to be opened,i tried the mouseDoubleClick function as shown above, but it also didn't work.
Any help?

Comment: Sendingmail sm = new Sendingmail();
            sm.Show();// this is what i did, and nothing happened, the form didnt open

Comment: Try sm.ShowDialog();

Comment: If that doesn't work then try placing a breakpoint on sm.Show(); and then debug your application. After that doubleclick the notifyicon1 and see what happens. If the breakpoint get's hit then we know where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

Did you declare the sm variable above?
Try declaring the form sm variable before the `sm.Show();` in your mousedoubleclick.

Comment: the sm value is the name of the new form which i declared at the top in the class

Comment: Aah okay, i thought so.. could you paste the rest of the code please? maybe that way we can help you better. Usually it has to work when you would use Ashok Patel's code.

Comment: public partial class Mainmenu : Form
    {
        Sendingmail sm = new Sendingmail();  // this is written at the beginnig, then we have the notification code, then the event called MouseDoubleClick shown above

Comment: try placing a breakpoint on sm.Show(); and then debug your application. After that doubleclick the notifyicon1 and see what happens. If the breakpoint get's hit then we know where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

on double click you should write code as below.

```
private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
     Form2 sm = new Form2();
     sm.Show();
}
```

//make sure you create new object of your SM form.

Comment: are you getting any exception or anything ? Is it calling that notification event on click.

Comment: i did display all the code, no exceptions no nothing

Comment: try to put debug point on double_click event and see. is debug point come there. May be the double click event not attached with it.

Comment: hey, I got your problem when you try to double click on your notifyIcon1 on a first click that goes hide. Try to put same code on single click.

Comment: I tried and made it  MouseClick instead of double, but also didn't work, the notification is just disappearing and no form is opening

Comment: add following code inside button6_Click function at bottom.

 `notifyIcon1.Click += (sender, e) =>
 {
   Sendingmail sm = new Sendingmail();
    sm.Show();
 };`

Answer (score 0):

add following code inside button6_Click function at bottom.

```
 notifyIcon1.Click += (sender, e) =>
 {
   Sendingmail sm = new Sendingmail();
    sm.Show();
 };
```